# Zend_Reflection doesn't get the docblock for certain classes

Tags: php, zend-framework, reflection, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use Zend_Reflection to read the docblock of certain classes:

Here is my code

```
  $r = new Zend_Reflection_Class($class);
  $docblock = $r->getDocblock();
```

It works for classes that have docblocks like this:

```
/**
 * Zend Framework
 *
 * LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the new BSD license that is bundled
 * with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@zend.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Barcode
 * @subpackage Renderer
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2011 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 * @version    $Id: Image.php 23775 2011-03-01 17:25:24Z ralph $
 */

/** @see Zend_Barcode_Renderer_RendererAbstract*/
require_once 'Zend/Barcode/Renderer/RendererAbstract.php';

/**
 * Class for rendering the barcode as image
 *
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Barcode
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2011 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 */
class Zend_Barcode_Renderer_Image extends Zend_Barcode_Renderer_RendererAbstract
```

But on the following class, which is a Doctrine 2 entity definition it doesn't work,

```
<?php
namespace DbEntities\Entity;

/**
 * Class for archived companies
 * 
 * @category DbEntities
 * @package Ycode_DbEntities
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2012
 * @licence Porprietory Code 
 * @Table(name="Archiveddeal",
 *      indexes={
 *          @index(name="textualIdentifier_idx", columns={"textualIdentifier"}),
 *          @index(name="rank_idx", columns={"rank"}),
 *          @index(name="realunique_idx", columns={"realunique"}),
 *          @index(name="coordinations_idx", columns={"latitude","longitude"})
 *      })
 * @Entity
 * @HumanFriendlyName = "Archived Companies"
 * @author Jim
 */
class Archivedcompany extends \Application_Model_Archivedcompany{
```

It throws the following error on line 2 of my code:

```
 No valid tag name found within provided docblock line
```

The value for $class for the first file is "Zend_Barcode_Renderer_Image", for the second file I tried both "DbEntities\Entity\Archivedcompany" and "\DbEntities\Entity\Archivedcompany" which return the same error.

I'm not sure if it's the namespace that confuses ZendReflection or not, when I use PHP's Reflection everything seems to work

```
 $rc = new ReflectionClass($class);
 $comments = $rc->getDocComment();
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What version of ZF do you use? Because I just checked that everything works ok.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem. I guess you have Windows line endings. Try to convert the line endings from Windows to Unix style.